# Different element text value returned during XML to JSON conversion Xquery Marklogic

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-10

We are working with the sample xml below and have a requirement to return it as JSON response.

So I'm using `json:transform-to-json()` function to do the XML to JSON conversion.

In the sample below , the value of `<title>` is not being returned as expected in JSON response when there are multiple child `<target>` elements.

E.g.

1. Title element with multiple target child elements

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace json = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

let $a := <title-group><title><target id="1">224</target><target id="2">225</target>Part II</title></title-group>
let $config := json:config("custom")
let $_ := map:put( $config, "array-element-names","target")
let $put :=  map:put($config,"whitespace","ignore")
return json:transform-to-json($a,$config)

Output :
{
"title-group": {
"title": {
"target": [
{
"id": "1", 
"_value": "224"
}, 
{
"id": "2", 
"_value": "225"
}
], 
"_value": "224225Part II"
}
}
}
```

2. Title element with single target child element

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace json = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

let $a := <title-group><title><target id="1">224</target>Part II</title></title-group>
let $config := json:config("custom")
let $put :=  map:put($config,"whitespace","ignore")
 return json:transform-to-json($a,$config)

Output :
{
"title-group": {
"title": {
"target": {
"id": "1", 
"_value": "224"
}, 
"_value": "Part II"
}
}
}
```

The `_value` for the `title` object differs when `target` is array/object. I want to understand how both scenarios work and on the below issues

1.what needs to be done to correct the title value in example 1?

2.If the XML is formatted like below, the newspace character is getting added to the json response _value.How to handle this scenario?

```
XML:
<title-group>
<title>
<target id="1">224</target>
Part II
</title>
</title-group>

JSON Output :
{
"title-group": {
"title": {
"target": {
"id": "1", 
"_value": "224"
}, 
"_value": "\nPart II\n"
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will address each of the concerns below individually:

As a start, it is important to understand a few of the main concepts about the conversion features as documented under [Conversion Philosophy](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/json#id_55967)

- Make it easy and fast to perform simple conversions using default conversion parameters.
- Make it possible to perform semantically lossless conversions.

There are more, but these two help with the context of the results.

When I test, I start with lossless and make sure that it still works 2 ways: `json:transform-from-json(json:transform-to-json($xml,$config), $config)`. Then I start to see what MarkLogic did with a one-way conversion.

```
<title-group>
  <title>
    <target id="1">224</target>
    <target id="2">225</target>
    Part II
  </title>
</title-group>
```

The key is "basic" conversions from the philosophy. In some cases, the desired conversion is not possible with just configuration even when using custom.

Your content is not simple and basic - it includes a combination of text and element nodes together (mixed content). Mixed content simply does not translate to JSON well. That is sort of like asking for this: `{ [{some object} {some object}] "string"}`.

Imagine having: *`The <b>quick</b> brown fox jumped over the <b>lazy</b> dog`*

So I can define an array with `quick`, `lazy` - but what happens to the original phrase: `The brown fox jumps over the dog`? Is that what i wanted? Probably not. Anything that is not "simple" is likely going to be unpredictable in conversion.

In the end, the extraction for the `array-element` is done and then the full value (perhaps concatenate of fn:data()) is done to capture the full value.

I agree that it works in this sample with a single target:

```
<title-group>
  <title>
    <target id="2">225</target>
    Part II
  </title>
</title-group>
```

However, one could argue that the value of title is still 225\nPart2

**Solutions to consider:**

I often have to massage the XML to make the conversion closer to what I desire. This is certainly the case to help with translation of mixed content nodes.   I usually accomplish this with simple XSLT transformations as a pre-processing step TO JSON and a post-processing step FROM JSON.

**Some examples:**
*Wrap the targets in a target element:*

```
<title-group>
  <title>
    <targets>
      <target id="1">224</target>
      <target id="2">225</target>
    </targets>
    Part II
  </title>
</title-group>
```

The result gives a JSON result that may be acceptable(although some people will be uncomfortable with the "extra layer" of structure. In addition,I find it a bit ugly based on my feeling that mixed-content nodes are not translatable to JSON as articulated in the fox sample.

*Wrap the value in a value element:*

```
<title-group>
  <title>
    <target id="1">224</target>
    <target id="2">225</target>
    <value>Part II</value>
  </title>
</title-group>
```

My preferred solution would be to actually wrap the target element in a targets element as well as the value because with a small change to the configuration, it is 2-way:

```
 <title-group>
  <title>
    <targets>
    <target id="1">224</target>
    <target id="2">225</target>
    </targets>
    <value>Part II</value>
  </title>
</title-group>
```

---

**Extra line return**

```
"_value": "\nPart II\n"
```

This is the expected output.  Please remember that the values are meant to be lossless(see original references). The confusion here may be about the configuration `whitespace=ignore` . It is true that `\n` is whitespace  - even in XMl. However, `whitespace=ignore` as part of the configuration

From [custom strategy properties](https://docs.marklogic.com/json:config):
How to handle XML text values that **only** contain whitespace when converting to JSON. Allowed values: "preserve", "ignore". Default: "preserve".

This is essentially about how to handle empty values and not what to do inside of content.

You will have to clean your data Yourself either before(`fn:normalize-space()` or after (such as using `Prototyp.trim()` in js)